# How can I find the amount of color in a certain area and compare it with another color using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors

I haven't the slightest clue how to do this, but I will give an example that hopefully an expert can use to provide a solution.

Let's say I have a 100x100 area that has two colors in random places, we'll say red and blue, and there are different amounts of each color every time the program is used.
How can I determine the amount of each color in this specific area and compare it with the other?

Ex: In the 100x100 area, 26% is red and 24% is blue, so the program determines the amount of red and blue in this area and prints that there is more red than blue.

If anyone could make a code for me it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow, is rather about fixing or improving attempted code, however in this case, you are asking someone for the solution/code without attempting it or giving a draft of what you have available. That is not how you use stackoverflow.

This problem can be solved with a loop that goes through each pixel
and assuming that only two colors are used red and blue, you can use a library like PIL, and get the rgb values of each pixel, compare them to the color of the red or blue pixel you know or the program produces, and then increment said counters to show the number of red or blue available. 100x100, means there are 10000 pixels. so the percentage is basically pixels_of_red_color / 10000.

Please do attempt solving this problem using code, and then I will edit my solution to deal with any faults.

Comment: Fair case, thank you for the help. I will attempt this code and I apologize for my misuse of the platform.